# XML документация с++ в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio-2015, документация

Недавно узнал, что `///` в Visual Studio используется для создания Xml документации. Также выяснил можно просматривать описание функций с помощью тега `<summary>`.

Вопрос. Работают ли теги `<returns>` и `<param name="_name_">`? Потому что при добавлении их в код, описание не меняется.

Пример кода:

```
/// <summary>
/// Заполняет массива до конца другой частью массива
/// </summary>
/// <param name="arr">массив требующий заполнения</param>
/// <param name="fullArr">массив, который заполняет arr</param>
/// <param name="startPos">с какой позиции заполнять</param>
/// <returns>заполненный массив</returns>
dynCharArr fillEndOfArr(dynCharArr arr, dynCharArr fullArr, int startPos)
{
    for (int i = startPos; i < fullArr.len; ++i)
       arr.arr[startPos + i] = fullArr.arr[i];

    return arr;
}
```

Что отображается в Visual Studio

[image: При наведении на функцию]

[image: При вводе параметров]

UPD
Заметил ещё такую проблему как полное отсутствие описания в окне Object Browser.

Comment: [должны работать](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177227(v=vs.140).aspx) вроде, кавычки в примерах одинарные только. Вернее в примере то как раз двойные, а в описании синтаксиса одинарные. Переоткрыть файл мб просто?

Comment: @teran Не очень понял с кавычками. Судя по докам, они должны быть двойными. Заметил ещё одну вещь в окне Object Browser описание отсутствует полностью.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему это баг старых версий VS. В Visual Studio 2019 (версия 16.8.3) проблема решена и комментарии к коду отображаются корректно.

Вот как это выглядит сейчас
[image]

Comment: На с++ обычно используют стиль doxygen :)

Comment: Да, сам пользуюсь doxygen, но на тот момент хотелось попробовать встроенные в VS средства :)